# Is there a relationship between a function's period and number of roots?

Tags: roots, periodic-functions, trigonometric-series

Let:
 $f(x,a,l)=\prod _{k=a}^l\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{k}\right)$ and

$f(x,k)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{k}\right)$

I came up with this equation to find the period 
$T(f(x,a,l))=2\,{{\pi }^{l-a+1} \left( \prod _{k=a}^{l} \left(  \sqrt{-{\frac {{
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}f(x,k)}{\int \!f(x,k)\,{\rm d}x}}} \right)  \right) ^{-1
} \left( \prod _{k=a}^{l}{\it ifactor} \left( {\frac {k}{(op(1,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right) )}} \right)  \right) ^{-1}}$

Note: ${op(1,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right)) }$=the smallest prime factorization of k

and

${{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right) }$, returns all factors of k

*Now I am looking for an equation correlating the period of $f(x,a,l)$, and its zeros; such that when integrated from one point to another it returns the amount of zeroes between those points. ie.
${\int_{q}^p \!W(T(f(x,a,l)),f(x,a,l))\,{\rm d}x}=$  count {${f(x,a,l)=0}$},q..p

Can someone please help, or provide guidance?***

**Simplification:**

$2\,{\pi  \left( \prod _{k=2}^{l} \left( \sqrt {-{\frac {{\frac {
\partial }{\partial x}}f \left( x,k \right) }{\int \!f \left( x,k
 \right) \,{\rm d}x}}} \right)  \right) ^{-1}}$

$f \left( x,k \right) =\sin \left( {\frac {\pi \,x}{k}} \right) $

${\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}f \left( x,k \right) ={\frac {\pi }{k}
\cos \left( {\frac {\pi \,x}{k}} \right) }
$

$-\int \!f \left( x,k \right) \,{\rm d}x={\frac {k}{\pi }\cos \left( {
\frac {\pi \,x}{k}} \right) }
$

${\frac {{\frac {\pi }{k}
\cos \left( {\frac {\pi \,x}{k}} \right) }}{{\frac {k}{\pi }\cos \left( {
\frac {\pi \,x}{k}} \right) }}}={\frac {{\pi }^{2}}{{k}^{2}}}$

$2\,{\pi  \left( \prod _{k=2}^{l} \left( \sqrt {-{\frac {{\frac {
\partial }{\partial x}}f \left( x,k \right) }{\int \!f \left( x,k
 \right) \,{\rm d}x}}} \right)  \right) ^{-1}}=2\,{\frac {\pi }{\prod _{k=a}^{l}\pi \, \sqrt{{k}^{-2}}}}=2\,{\frac {
\pi \,{\pi }^{a} \sqrt{ \left( \Gamma  \left( a \right)  \right) ^{-2}
}}{{\pi }^{l-a} \sqrt{ \left( \Gamma  \left( l+1 \right)  \right) ^{-2
}}}}$

$T(a,l)={\frac {2\,{\frac {
\pi \,{\pi }^{a} \sqrt{ \left( \Gamma  \left( a \right)  \right) ^{-2}
}}{{\pi }^{l-a} \sqrt{ \left( \Gamma  \left( l+1 \right)  \right) ^{-2
}}}}}{\left(\prod _{k=a}^{l}{\it ifactor} \left( {\frac {k}{(op(1,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right) )}} \right)  \right)}} $

Through cancellation of ${\pi }->$

${2\,{\frac {\sqrt { \left( \Gamma  \left( a \right)  \right) ^{-2}}}{
\sqrt { \left( \Gamma  \left( 1+l \right)  \right) ^{-2}}{\left(\prod _{k=a}^{l}{\it ifactor} \left( {\frac {k}{(op(1,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right) )}} \right)  \right)}}}={\frac {2\Gamma  \left( 1+l \right) }{\Gamma  \left( a \right)2(PF\left({(k)}\right)}}}$

*A 2 can come out due to a 'strange factorization of 4'
and implying 4 lies between a and l

$={\frac {l!}{ \left( a-1 \right) !\,\left(PF({k})\right)}}$

*PF is Strange Prime Factorization

PF(4)=2

PF(Prime)=1

${op(2,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right)) }={\frac {k }{{op(1,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right)) }}}=$Largest factor of K

$PF(k) = 
\prod\cases{
2  & \text{if } k = 4\cr
1 & \text{if } k\in {Primes}
\cr
2*\prod _{k=a}^l{op(2,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right)) } & \text{if } k\not\in {Primes}
}$

Practical solution 
$PF(k) = 
\prod\cases{
2  & \text{if } k = 4\cr
1 & \text{if } 0< \left| \prod _{u=2}^{k-1}-i/2 \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {ik\pi }{u}}}
}-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-ik\pi }{u}}}} \right) uk \right|
\cr
2*\prod _{k=a}^l{op(2,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right)) } & \text{if } \left| \prod _{u=2}^{k-1}-i/2 \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {ik\pi }{u}}}
}-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-ik\pi }{u}}}} \right) uk \right|
= 0
}$

$T(a,l)={ {\frac {2*l!}{ \left( a-1 \right) !{\prod\cases{
2  & \text{if } k = 4\cr
1 & \text{if } 0< \left| \prod _{u=2}^{k-1}-i/2 \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {ik\pi }{u}}}
}-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-ik\pi }{u}}}} \right) uk \right|
\cr
2*\prod _{k=a}^l{op(2,{\it ifactor}
 \left( k \right)) } & \text{if } \left| \prod _{u=2}^{k-1}-i/2 \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {ik\pi }{u}}}
}-{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-ik\pi }{u}}}} \right) uk \right|
= 0}} }}}
$

Comment: Where does the equation for $T(f)$ come from?! Isn't the period here just the smallest $T$ such that $T/k$ is an even integer for all k? Prime-factor $a=p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2}...$, $a+1 =p_1^{b_1} p_2^{b_2}...$, and so on up to $l$ we have $T = p_1^{\max(a_1,b_1,...)}p_2^{\max(a_2,b_2,...)}...$

Comment: It's not that simple. The reason I made it like this was because the function f(x,a,l) has periods that change almost eradicly due to the multiplication of functions f(x,k),in which each f(x) has different periods ,respectively.I found a relation ship which had to be added to produce correct results (the last term). This can be seen by using a tool like [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=period+of+sin%28pi*x%2F2%29sin%28pi*x%2F3%29)  and continue to add new terms to the equation (...sin(pi*x/3)sin(pi*x/4)...).

Comment: Well the formula you gave is wrong (the period can not depend on $f(x)$). The one I gave above will give you a period of $f$ (btw missing a factor of 2 infront). You can check for yourself that for, say, $f(x) = \sin(\pi/3 x)\sin(\pi/4 x)\sin(\pi/5 x)\sin(\pi/6 x)$ that $T = 2\times 2^2 \times 3^1 \times 5^1 = 120$ is the period.

Comment: My function returns the same results, so it's not wrong. Its not elegant either. Also when I said f(x), I meant a single term of f(x,k) where k is defined; {..,sin(pi*x/1),sin(pi*x/2..}. My function allows for the function to be pluged in as is, then breaks it down into f(x)'s,which are broken down to get each one's individual period.

Comment: Well, why do you have the $df/dx$ and $\int f dx$ term there? For your function $df/dx = -\pi^2/k^2\int f dx$ so that you can remove this term (keep the $k$) and remove the $\pi^{.}$ term infront and you should be left with the same formula as I have.

Comment: oh my, you just helped me relize an even simpler version still dependens on the individual %T(x)% values.

Comment: Ok.I simplified it some, I must have overlooked them.